# Show what pages users from a city viewed in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

I am trying to see what pages users from St. Louis, MO have visited on my webpage. I can see the number of users from St. Louis. I found a section that showed the user flow from cities but it only shows the top cities with most traffic which St. Louis is not a part of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going into the Behavior/Site Content/All Pages view.

From there you can add a secondary dimension, choosing City.If you click on the Advanced Filter, you can choose to limit the City filter to

Include : City : Containing : "St. Louis"

This should allow you to start to see that traffic detail you are looking for.

(from STL) Chris

Comment: Thanks Chris, you saved my day(s)

Comment: Chris, is there any way in Google analytics with which I can also see the keyword used by the user because of which he/she reached that page.